# Pass argument in .each(&:) function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've an entity and I want to call each element in the entity with a function and pass an argument with it.

I know I can call the function by using `entity.each(&:calculate)` but I want to pass argument to the function.

```
def calculate(x)
  puts "#{x}"
end
```

I'm trying with `entity.each(&:calculate, x)`

Comment: The answer is: `entity.each { |e| e.calculate(x) }`

Comment: You can use lambdas: `calc = ->(e) { e.calculate(x) }; entity.each(&calc)` or `calc = ->(x) { ->(e) { e.calculate(x) } }; entity.each(&calc[x])`. Doesn't seem worth it in a simple case like this though.

Answer (score 5):

Here `&` converts the method to a proc. As far as I'm aware allowing passing arguments is an open issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12115

I would simply call the block explicitly

```
entity.each{ |el| el.calculate(x) }
```